# Finding a way to identify data type of a variable in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I believe my problem can be explained by the following code snippet

```
#define stingify(str) #str

int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("%s\n" , stringify(typeof(a)));
    return 0;
}
```

I want the `typeof()` macro to be expanded first then the `stringify()` macro to get my expected output "int" as a string.
Is there any possible way for this?

Comment: `typeof` is not a macro. The preprocessor has no idea about types. This will never work.

Comment: Besides not being a macro, [`typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) just doesn't work the way you seem to expect.

Comment: What is your use case, why do you need this? At compile time, the type of any object is fixed in C. Therefore, your code _knows_ the type.

Answer (score 2):

With pure standard C, you can use `_Generic`:

```
#define stringify_typeof(obj)  \
  _Generic((obj),              \
           int:    "int",      \
           double: "double")   \
```

If you want this type list more maintainable, you could move it into an X macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SUPPORTED_TYPES(X)     \
  X(int)                       \
  X(double)                    \
/* keep on adding types here */

#define GENERIC_LIST(type) ,type: #type
#define stringify_typeof(obj) _Generic((obj) SUPPORTED_TYPES(GENERIC_LIST) )

int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("%s\n" , stringify_typeof(a));

    double b;
    printf("%s\n" , stringify_typeof(b));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use genetic macros if you want to print the type name.

```
char *typei()
{
    return "signed integer";
}

char *typeui()
{
    return "unsigned integer";
}

char *typef()
{
    return "float";
}

char *typeunk()
{
    return "unknown";
}

#define type(X) _Generic((X), \
        int: typei, \
        unsigned: typeui,  \
        float: typef,  \
        default: typeunk \
        )(X)
 
int main(void)
{
    const float y = 2.0f;

    printf("The type is: %s\n", type(y));
    printf("The type is: %s\n", type(3.0));
    printf("The type is: %s\n", type(3));
    printf("The type is: %s\n", type(3U));
    printf("The type is: %s\n", type(3LU));
}
```

Output:

```
The type is: float
The type is: unknown
The type is: signed integer
The type is: unsigned integer
The type is: unknown
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WMr5xs5os